# Only change style of class clicked between multiple classes have same name

Tags: jquery, css, class, onclick, styles

I have many icons with the same class which I want to change the style the icon that I click. I set one `display` is `none` and other is `inline` as default and when I click it will be reserved. But it affected to all icons has same class name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-calendar-plus-o, .fa-check").click(function(){
      $('.fa-calendar-plus-o').css({"display":"none"});
      $('.fa-check').css({"display":"inline"});
    });
  });
```

I try to use `$(this).css({"display":"none"});` but I don't know how to defined `this` for each of them.

Comment: can you provide the html

Comment: try this:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-calendar-plus-o, .fa-check").click(function(){
      $(this).css({"display":"none"});
      $('.fa-check').css({"display":"inline"});
    });
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the one you clicked, and display the hidden one next to it?

(here I'm assuming that `fa-calendar-plus-o` is before `fa-check`, if not you just need to swap `next` and `prev`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fa-calendar-plus-o").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    $(this).next('.fa-check').css({
      "display": "inline"
    });
  });
  $(".fa-check").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    $(this).prev('.fa-calendar-plus-o').css({
      "display": "inline"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.fa-check {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="fa-calendar-plus-o">Im fa-calendar-plus-o1</span>
<span class="fa-check">Im fa-check1</span>
<br>
<span class="fa-calendar-plus-o">Im fa-calendar-plus-o2</span>
<span class="fa-check">Im fa-check2</span>
<br>
<span class="fa-calendar-plus-o">Im fa-calendar-plus-o3</span>
<span class="fa-check">Im fa-check3</span>
<br>
<span class="fa-calendar-plus-o">Im fa-calendar-plus-o4</span>
<span class="fa-check">Im fa-check4</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

way to do that by using `.filter()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".fa-calendar-plus-o, .fa-check").click(function(){
     $(this).filter('.fa-calendar-plus-o').css({"display":"none"});
     $(this).filter('.fa-check').css({"display":"inline"});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting with one hidden already this is really easy to accomplish with toggleClass. Just apply the .hidden class to the one that is initially hidden after you do that you can just toggle using the a slightly modified version of your code:

CSS:

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-calendar-plus-o, .fa-check").click(function(){
    $(this).filter('.fa-calendar-plus-o').toggleClass("hidden")
    $(this).filter('.fa-check').toggleClass("hidden")
    })
  });
```